# Coil svg is not loading image with proguard on

Tags: android, svg, proguard, coil

I am using following implementation of coil for loading svg image

```
// in gradle build
implementation 'io.coil-kt:coil-svg:1.4.0'
```

with extension function to load svg as

```
fun ImageView.loadUrl(url: String) {

val imageLoader = ImageLoader.Builder(this.context)
    .componentRegistry { add(SvgDecoder(this@loadUrl.context)) }
    .build()

val request = ImageRequest.Builder(this.context)
    .crossfade(true)
    .crossfade(500)
    .data(url)
    .target(this)
    .build()

imageLoader.enqueue(request)
}
```

loading image in coroutine scope as

```
  account.addressQrcode?.let { qrCodeAddress ->

        img_qrCode.loadUrl(qrCodeAddress)
        qrItemLoader.isVisible = false
 }
```

which is perfectly working with proguard off, but after turning my proguard on as

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

coil is not able to load image, i have read [there documentation](https://github.com/coil-kt/coil) they say that they dont need any explicitly proguard rules. which they need for coroutines, okhttp and okio i have already included that in mine.

let me know if i am missing something here...

Comment: have you tried [asking here?](https://community.guardsquare.com/)

Comment: Anything in the logs? Maybe add a listener to `coil` & check if something is logged by the library.